# Fabric is not resending invitation neither any report email

Tags: twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I've left a company and the email used to access Fabric has been removed.

Now I am working in the same company and they recreated the email with the same handle. I don't know if this is the problem but I'm not receiving any email with reports and I didn't receive the Beta Tester invitation.

My status is active and the interface says that an invitation has been sent. But I'm not receiving anything.

I deleted my user from Organization using another admin account. After that I've invited my user again. No email sent at all.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. The most likely issue is that when you left the company, our mail server recorded a bounce for a no longer valid email address. Even with the address, re-created, our mail server would still have a bounce for the address. I'd recommend sharing your email address or emailing into support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can verify that and clear the bounce if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, Mike
I will send and email to support.
If they resolve this issue I will mark this answer as correct.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear you're all set :)

Comment: @MikeBonnell After signing up on fabric, Email is not triggering. i have send a mail support@fabric.io.

Comment: This was due to a production issue - http://status.fabric.io/incidents/2z9qhpszppbp